# Pandas: why doesn't dot product work even after choosing the correct number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take the dot product of a pandas DataFrame and Series. However, even when I restrict the pandas DataFrame to have the same number of columns as the Series, I still get

> ValueError: matrices are not aligned.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, -2, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, -2, -1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 1])

print(df1.shape) # (2,4)
print(df2.iloc[:, 1:len(df2.columns)].shape) #(2,4) also

df1.dot(s) # works fine
df2.iloc[:, 1:len(df2.columns)].dot(s) # throws ValueError
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Which variable do you mean by `df`, `df1` or `df2`?

Comment: Sorry, df2. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the columns are 1,2,.. but index seires is 0,1,...You need:

```
df2.iloc[:, 1:len(df2.columns)].values.dot(s)
```

or

```
df2.values[:,1:].dot(s)
```

**Output**

```
#array([-2,  5])
```

**Another approach** [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df2.rename(columns = dict(zip(df2.columns,df2.columns + -1))).iloc[:,1:].dot(s)
```

or

```
n = 1
df2.iloc[:,n:].rename(columns = dict(zip(df2.columns[n:],s.index))).dot(s)
#0   -2
#1    5
#dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the indices that don't match!
If you convert both `df2` and `s` to arrays it works:

```
> df2.iloc[:, 1:len(df2.columns)].values @ s.values
array([-2,  5])
```

Also If you have the index of s start with 1:

```
> s.index = [1,2,3,4]
> df2.iloc[:, 1:len(df2.columns)].dot(s)
0   -2
1    5
dtype: int64
```